How to use Like function VBA?
I am new in VBA could you please help me for this loop please. It is a simple copy and paste with a if.
Sub reverse_convertible()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

For Col = 3 To 20
    For i = 1 To 20
        If Worksheets("Worksheets").Range("C" & i) Like "*Products*" And Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) Then          
            Worksheets("Aggregate Table").Rows(Col) = Worksheets("Worksheets").Rows(i)
        End If
    Next i
Next Col

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Copy and Paste data if the Products is in the initial text cell

Worksheets("Aggregate Table").Rows(Col).value = Worksheets("Worksheets").Rows(i).value will work. But your problem is that you are overwriting Worksheets("Aggregate Table").Rows(Col).value per each i.

Cannot set explicitely a Range to another Range. Use the Copy method like this
Worksheets("Worksheets").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Aggregate Table").Rows(Col)
or you can use the Value property of the source range
Worksheets("Worksheets").Rows(i) = Worksheets("Aggregate Table").Rows(Col).Value
